# Impersonate user with admin credentials in ApacheDS

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I want to implement FORGOT password and I need to set the new password for the user without knowing the original one. Because of that I cannot authenticate to `LDAP (ApacheDS)` with the user credentials. However, when I change the password using the admin credentials the `password policy` is not applied.

So, I'm trying to see if I can authenticate as the admin but act as the user. Is there any way to implement this functionality against `ApacheDS`.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the Proxied Authorization Control as defined in [RFC 4370](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4370). I am not an Apache DS expert, but I could find the following control on their [site](https://directory.apache.org/api/gen-docs/latest/apidocs/org/apache/directory/api/ldap/model/message/controls/ProxiedAuthz.html).

The ldap.com site also has an [example](https://docs.ldap.com/ldap-sdk/docs/getting-started/controls.html) on how to use this control (Scroll down to the section called *The Proxied Authorization Request Controls*. The code snippet is using the [UnboundID LDAP SDK for Java](https://www.ldap.com/unboundid-ldap-sdk-for-java))

I hope this helps.

Comment: This looked like what I was looking for, but sadly ApacheDS does not implement this Control. I actually looked at their implementation in `AuthenticationInterceptor` and they are skipping most of the password policy (the password history is not skipped) if the current session is of an Admin.